# delete replication using script

Tags: replication, sql-server-2012

im using sql server 2012 and replication process in it. now the replication process is working correctly, but i want to delete this replication, i mean all the publications, subscriptions and articles through script. i went through this site http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324401 and tried the following script

```
:setvar PublisherDatabase "AdventureWorks2012"
:setvar SubscriberServer "HYDHTC0131320D\MSSQLSERVER2"

use [$(PublisherDatabase)]

--Drop all subscriptions
exec sp_dropsubscription  
@publication = N'TestPubs',
@article = N'all',
--@subscriber = [$(SubscriberServer)]
@subscriber = N'all',
@destination_db = N'all'

--Drop publication
if exists (Select 1 From SysPublications where name = N'TestPubs')
EXEC sp_droppublication @publication = N'TestPubs'

EXEC sp_replicationdboption @dbname = [$(PublisherDatabase)], @optname = N'publish', @value = N'false'

--Drop subscriber entry
EXEC sp_dropsubscriber @subscriber = [$(SubscriberServer)]

--Drop distributor
EXEC sp_dropdistributor @no_checks = 1
```

after i execute the above script, im getting the following error.

```
Only one Log Reader Agent or log-related procedure (sp_repldone, sp_replcmds, and sp_replshowcmds) can connect to a database at a time. If you executed a log-related procedure, drop the connection over which the procedure was executed or execute sp_replflush over that connection before starting the Log Reader Agent or executing another log-related procedure.

Msg 18752, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_replcmds, Line 1

Only one Log Reader Agent or log-related procedure (sp_repldone, sp_replcmds, and sp_replshowcmds) can connect to a database at a time. If you executed a log-related procedure, drop the connection over which the procedure was executed or execute sp_replflush over that connection before starting the Log Reader Agent or executing another log-related procedure.

The Subscriber was dropped.

Msg 20015, Level 16, State 1, Procedure 

sp_MSreplremoveuncdir, Line 83
Could not remove directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ReplData\unc\HYDHTC0131320D_ADVENTUREWORKS2012_TESTPUBS\20120719152739\'. Check the security context of xp_cmdshell and close other processes that may be accessing the directory.
```

check this screenshot for more details

[image]

can anyone help me in solving these issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you had some errors when dropping replication and have some orphaned subscription metadata at teh Subscriber.  Orphaned metadata can be removed from the subscription database using [sp_removedbreplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188734.aspx).

For future reference, you can remove all subscriptions, publications, and disable publishing and distribution following these steps:

- [Delete a Push Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151212.aspx)
- [How to: Delete a Publication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147833.aspx)
- [Disabling Publishing and Distribution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151181.aspx)

**Relevant bits of code from the links**

a) To drop a push subscription on **transactional** replication

```
-- This batch is executed at the Publisher to remove 
-- a pull or push subscription to a transactional publication.
DECLARE @publication AS sysname;
DECLARE @subscriber AS sysname;
SET @publication = N'AdvWorksProductTran';
SET @subscriber = $(SubServer);

USE [AdventureWorks2012]
EXEC sp_dropsubscription 
  @publication = @publication, 
  @article = N'all',
  @subscriber = @subscriber;
GO
```

b) To drop a subscription on a **merge** replication

```
DECLARE @publication AS sysname;
DECLARE @subscriber AS sysname;
DECLARE @subscriptionDB AS sysname;
SET @publication = N'AdvWorksSalesOrdersMerge';
SET @subscriber = $(SubServer);
SET @subscriptionDB = N'AdventureWorks2012Replica';

USE [AdventureWorks2012]
EXEC sp_dropmergesubscription 
  @publication = @publication, 
  @subscriber = @subscriber, 
  @subscriber_db = @subscriptionDB;
GO
```

c) To drop a publication and set a *source DB* to stop being a publisher, on a **transactional** replication.

```
DECLARE @publicationDB AS sysname;
DECLARE @publication AS sysname;
SET @publicationDB = N'AdventureWorks2008R2'; 
SET @publication = N'AdvWorksProductTran'; 

-- Remove a transactional publication.
USE [AdventureWorks2008R2]
EXEC sp_droppublication @publication = @publication;

-- Remove replication objects from the database.
USE [master]
EXEC sp_replicationdboption 
  @dbname = @publicationDB, 
  @optname = N'publish', 
  @value = N'false';
GO
```

d) To drop a publication and set a *source DB* to stop being a publisher, on a **merge** replication.

```
DECLARE @publication AS sysname
DECLARE @publicationDB    AS sysname
SET @publication = N'AdvWorksSalesOrdersMerge' 
SET @publicationDB = N'AdventureWorks2008R2'

-- Remove the merge publication.
USE [AdventureWorks2008R2]
EXEC sp_dropmergepublication @publication = @publication;

-- Remove replication objects from the database.
USE master
EXEC sp_replicationdboption 
  @dbname = @publicationDB, 
  @optname = N'merge publish', 
  @value = N'false'
GO
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, for "Only one Log Reader Agent or log-related procedure " error, I suppose, I have to stop the logreader agent and for "Could not remove directory..." error, I missed some permissions for the folder.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to do `sp_droppublication` in a transaction.

```
-- local variables
declare
 @return_code    int -- return code of sp
,@dependent_publ sysname -- publication dependent on replicated RDZ tables

declare a cursor for
select distinct p.name from syspublications p
 inner join sysarticles s on p.pubid = s.pubid 
 inner join adm_replicated_rdz_tables r on r.table_name = s.name

if exists
 (select * from sys.objects
   where object_id = object_id('[dbo].[sysarticles]') and type in ('U'))
begin
 open a; fetch next from a into @dependent_publ; while @@fetch_status = 0
 begin
  begin transaction
   print @dependent_publ
   execute sp_droppublication @dependent_publ;
  commit
  fetch next from a into @dependent_publ;
 end; close a; deallocate a;
end
```